# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo on some devices

Tags: android, android-activity

I´m currently facing yet another weired error, which only occurs on some devices.

Here is the Stack-trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.android.c/de.android.cc.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3877)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class  <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
    at      com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
    at de.android.cc.clean.a.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.q.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.q.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.q.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.q.l(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.i.onStart(Unknown Source)
    at de.android.cc.MainActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.q.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.q.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.q.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.q.l(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.i.onStart(Unknown Source)
    at de.android.cc.MainActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1188)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5382)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3877)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.q.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.q.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.q.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.q.l(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.i.onStart(Unknown Source)
    at de.android.contactscleaner2lib.MainActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1188)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5382)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3877)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.q.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.q.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.q.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.q.l(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.i.onStart(Unknown Source)
    at de.android.cc.MainActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1188)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5382)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3877)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
```

What could generally cause such a bug?

One of the devices was N7000

Edit:

Postet the wrong Stacktrace first

Comment: You have a NullPointerException in the `getCount()` of an ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Check you ArrayAdapter for null

Comment: you are right, sry I got two such errors, but this one is the right one now. Corrected my initial posting

Comment: Your fragment `onCreateView()` inflates a layout that has problem on line 7. Possible nested "caused by" exception is not shown here... So check your layout first.

Comment: But I´m using this layout for every screen size and it works perfectly on all others